# how can i create a tagging system using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, tags, tagging

wondering how i can create a tagging system in php and with a mysql database, my initial thoughts were to create a row in the table where the articles are stored, named tags, and list the tags seperated by commas, but i am not sure how i can create a query that searches for matching tags, i dont want to have to query every article everytime someone clicks a tag. can anyone help?

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on "database normalization". A good start would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're describing a many-to-many relationship between Articles and Tags. You'd want to use an intermediate junction table to resolve that relationship.

[image]

Now, to find all articles that match a selected tag:

```
SELECT a.article_title
    FROM Tag t
        INNER JOIN Article_Tag_Xref atx
            ON t.tag_id = atx.tag_id
        INNER JOIN Article a
            ON atx.article_id = a.article_id
    WHERE t.tag_name = 'SelectedTagName'
```

Comment: What about finding all articles that match all tags of a given list?

Comment: seems like there are 3 ways to do this 1) denormalized table with all tags as part of main table 2) 2 tables with the main have item id and second having item id and tag where both item id and tag are indexed and 3) the structure you described

Answer (score 2):

tbl_articles has articleID, etc.

tbl_tags has tagID, etc.

tbl_taggedarticles has taggedArticleID, articleID, tagID

```
SELECT articleID FROM tbl_taggedarticles WHERE tagID = "searchedID"
```